# HTML5: Oninput - Is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

The code below does not work. The console returns the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: amount is not defined".

However, the "amount" and "resultPriceAmount" are defined. I called them in another way?

```
<form oninput="resultPriceAmount.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value) * 29.90).toFixed(2); amount.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value)); message.value = amount.value + ' - R$ ' + resultPriceAmount.value;">
 1<input type="range" id="rangeAmount" min="1" max="3" value="1">3
 <a href="#" class="button">Buy <output name="message" for="rangeAmount"></output></a>
</form>
```

***Edit:***
This way works, but the code gets confused.

> ```
> <form oninput="message.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value)) + ' - R$ ' + (parseInt(rangeAmount.value) * 29.90).toFixed(2);">
> ```

That's what I want to avoid (I'll do something bigger later)

Comment: there is no field with name/id `amount`

Comment: What about this is HTML5 specific?

Comment: @j08691 `oninput` and `<output>`, though it's really a js question.

Comment: why do you have so many JS codes inline? Also, do not use `href="#"`; browser will scroll to top once you click the `<a>` tag

Comment: @j08691 also, input `type="range"` is HTML5 specific.

Comment: oninput has been around a while, but the range type I can see as HTML5. Good catch @Raptor.

Comment: @j08691 HTML5 has been around a while, `oninput` isn't part of HTML4 spec as far as I know..

Comment: @raptor, thanks, but this is a simplified version of my actual code, in order to facilitate explanation

Comment: You should learn about other ways to bind event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: *"However, the "amount" and "resultPriceAmount" are defined."* **Where** exactly is `amount` defined? Clearly it's not defined, otherwise you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: @FelixKling Where: _<form oninput="[...] **amount.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value));** [...]">_ but I see confusing me (see comments in the message progysm). Has some way to collect values ​​that place?

Comment: @KeplerBR: You are not defining `amount` there. You are trying to **access**  `amount`, assuming that it returns an object and assign a value to the property `value`. And that's why you get the error. You are trying to access an undeclared variable. `amount` would have to be defined as `var amount = {};` for this to work. If you just want to store the value of the field in a variable, then do that: `var amount = parseInt(rangeAmount.value);`

Comment: Thank you very much solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variable (var) instead of HTML input.
http://jsfiddle.net/7c9eE/6/

```
<form oninput="var resultPriceAmount = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value) * 29.90).toFixed(2); var amount = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value)); message.value = amount + ' - R$ ' + resultPriceAmount">
 1<input type="range" id="rangeAmount" min="1" max="3" value="1">3
 <a href="#" class="button">Buy <output name="message" for="rangeAmount"></output></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use variables instead of getting the input element by the id.  You could use something such as:

```
document.getElementById('rangeAmount')
```

instead of:

```
rangeAmount
```

Or, you could keep it as is, but define this before using any variables:

```
rangeAmount = document.getElementById('rangeAmount')
```

and, obviously, do the same for the other non-working variables.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not necessary for my case and this is not the error.

Comment: In that case, this is not the full code, which leaves a wide range of ambiguity.  Based on solely this code, it could be because you have no element with the id of `amount` nor `resultPriceAmount`, but it's not possible to know for sure since you do not show how these variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

It says there is no element with id/name `amount` see

```
<form oninput="resultPriceAmount.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value) * 29.90).toFixed(2); amount.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value)); message.value = amount.value + ' - R$ ' + resultPriceAmount.value;">1
    <input type="range" id="rangeAmount" min="1" max="3" value="1" />3
    <a href="#" class="button">Buy<output name="message" for="rangeAmount"></output></a>
</form>
<input id="resultPriceAmount" />
<input id="amount" value="2"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7c9eE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

lack `/>` `<input type="range" id="rangeAmount" min="1" max="3" value="1">`

```
<form oninput="resultPriceAmount.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value) * 29.90).toFixed(2); amount.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value)); message.value = amount.value + ' - R$ ' + resultPriceAmount.value;">
 1<input type="range" id="rangeAmount" min="1" max="3" value="1">3
 <a href="#" class="button">Buy <output name="message" for="rangeAmount"></output></a>
</form>
```

other example

```
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">0
<input type="range" id="a" value="50">100 +
<input type="number" id="b" value="50">=
<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work when you put the input inside the form.
http://jsfiddle.net/7c9eE/5/

```
<form oninput="resultPriceAmount.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value) * 29.90).toFixed(2); amount.value = (parseInt(rangeAmount.value)); message.value = amount.value + ' - R$ ' + resultPriceAmount.value;">1
    <input type="range" id="rangeAmount" min="1" max="3" value="1" />3
    <a href="#" class="button">Buy<output name="message" for="rangeAmount"></output></a>
<input id="resultPriceAmount" />
<input id="amount" value="2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, however, this is not a good method. Ideally collect the value set in oninput own without creating more elements.

Comment: I was fixing Arun P Johny example, I don't understand your code since there is no amount in your example.

Comment: Yes there is value. "amount" and "resultPriceAmount" were defined at the beginning of "oninput" and they are what I wish to call.

Comment: are you mixing html input with variable?

Comment: I believe that this is my mistake. I tried to set variables within the "oninput", however, did not work.